# Friendly URLs in Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rails-routing

How has Github managed to get friendly URLs for representing repos of users? For a project called `abc`  by username `foo`, how do they work around with a URL like: `http://github.com/foo/abc`. Are they fetching the `abc` model for the DB from the title in the URL (which sounds unreasonable as they are modifying the titles). How are they transferring the unique ID of the `abc` repo which they can fetch and show in the view?

The reason I ask is that I am facing a similar problem of creating friendlier URLs to view a resource. MongoDB's object IDs are quite long and make the URL look horrific. Is there a workaround? All the tutorials that demonstrate CRUD (or REST) URLs for a resource always include the object's unique ID(e.g. `http://mysite.org/post/1` or `http://mysite.org/post/1/edit`. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mocked a structure like this using FriendlyID and [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Essentially, use friendly ID to get the `to_param`-ish slugs in your routes, then set up nested resources. Using GitHub as an example:

*routes.rb*

```
resources :users do
  resources :repositories
end
```

Then in your controller, say, for repositories, you can check the existence of `params[:user_id]` and use that to determine the user from the route. The reason I check for existence is because I did something like (roughly):

```
/myrepositories/:repository_id
/:user_id/:repository_id
```

So my controller does:

```
def show
  @user = params[:user_id] ? User.find(params[:user_id]) : current_user
end
```

I followed this tutorial [here](http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs) to get started with this same project.

Answer (score 4):

Not having seen their code, I couldn't tell you exactly how they do it, but if you're using Rails there are at least two Ruby gems that will give you similar results:

Take a look at [Slugged](https://github.com/Sutto/slugged) and [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Comment: Github uses Rails so likely does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/foo/abc is a unique repository identifier (for that repo's master branch). I'd assume that somewhere they have a table that looks like:

```
repository-id | user-id | project-id
```

and are just looking up based on user and project rather than repository-id.

You'd need to do some domain-specific mapping between internal and user-friendly ids, but you'd need to make sure that was a 1:1 mapping.

Answer (score 1):

See this rails cast on methods, gems and solutions to common problems you might get while modifying the application to use friendly urls.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

(although Ryan Bates deserves the rep+ for this)

Answer (score 0):

This is called *URL rewriting* if the web server does it (such as Apache), and *routing* when it happens in a web application framework (such as Ruby on Rails).

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html